# Rescue All Files From (a Maybe Dead) Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, files, data-recovery

I am unable to get on Ubuntu so I want to rescue my art files. But I don't know how.
I never did this before and I never experienced this before in an upgrade ether, I'm Kind of scared at the moment.
How can I rescue my MyPaint, pictures and other files from (a maybe dead) Ubuntu using Windows HP 7?

I need all the help I can get at the moment.
I also might need some visual help too.

I only have 1 computer.....

Comment: What version of Ubuntu (12.04 !?) is installed?  And yes, you will need to use Ubuntu to recover those files ..  (See answer below)

Answer (score 2):

Go to another computer or use your Windows 7 installation, simply download an actual Ubuntu image and make a bootable USB stick described on homepage from ubuntu.com. Boot from these USB stick and choose "Try Ubuntu". Now put a clean second USB stick or HDD into another USB port and save your documents from your computer HDD or move the file and folders to the windows partition.

PS: It does not work, if you have encryption enabled by installation.

Comment: or 'try ubuntu' using a live cd (the downloaded ubuntu iso burned on a cd)

Answer (score 0):

Simply install Ext2Read (http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/) on your windows device and then you'll be able to browse your Ubuntu files as well. (Works only if encryption is not enabled)

You can also repair your GRUB if you cannot use Ubuntu to log in to Ubuntu back.